# How to focus a button in a details list using React and Office Fabric

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

Anyone have suggestions on how to focus a button in react DetailsList?  Refs seem like the way to go, and I'd like to do something like this:

```
        findDOMNode<HTMLButtonElement>(this.refs.mybutton).focus()
```

But I haven't been able to get a ref handle on the button element.

One approach I've tried is in my DetailsList:

```
        <DetailsList
            onRenderItemColumn={this.renderItemColumn}
            ref={(list) => {this.detailsList = list;}}
            ....
        />
```

And the button I want to focus (coming from renderItemColumn):

```
                <PrimaryButton
                    onClick={() => this.handleActionSelection(fieldContent)}
                    ariaDescription={buttonText}
                    text={buttonText}
                    ref={"ButtonIWantToFocus"}
                />
```

In didComponentMount() I can now get access to the DetailList, but I'm not sure how to get the button ref to focus.

Alternatively I can define the button as:

```
                    <PrimaryButton
                        disabled={true}
                        ariaDescription={buttonText}
                        text={buttonText}
                        ref={(button) => {this.focusButton = button;}}
                    />
```

This give me a handle to the button, but it has no focus(), function.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are not referencing the `ref` correctly (you don't need `findDOMNode`).
After you set and attach your `ref` to the class instance using the `this` key word you just reference it using the `this` key word.

Here is a small example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  focusBtn = () => {
    this.btn.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.focusBtn}>click here to focus the button below</div>
        <hr/>
        <button ref={ref => {this.btn = ref}}>im a button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
Sorry i just noticed you were talking about a component (not just a component but a library component of `fabric-ui`).
After doing some reading on their github page i found out you should use the prop `componentRef` instead of `ref`.
Here is the relevant example with `fabric-ui`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  focusBtn = () => {
    this.btn.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.focusBtn}>click here to focus the button below</div>
        <hr/>
        <Fabric.PrimaryButton componentRef={ref => {this.btn = ref}}>im a button</Fabric.PrimaryButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
button.ms-Button.ms-Button--primary.css-32:focus{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I think the issue is related to OfficeFabric.  The PrimaryButton element has no focus() function.   The only way I've been able to focus it (when not in a table) is via:  findDOMNode<HTMLButtonElement>(this.refs.doneExtractingButton).focus();

Comment: sorry just noticed you are using a component and not a dom element. after short reading you should use their `prop` `componentRef` instead of `ref`. i will update my example

Comment: Fantastic.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Lars no problems. Did it  fixed your problem?

Comment: So slightly more complicated the DetailsList property "onRenderItemColumn" function (which is what creates the Button) is only called *after* componentDidUpdate() is called - so there's nothing to trigger the focus off of.  I was able to work around it by setting a delay with a 500ms timer.  Not pretty but it works.